# Bosun how to merge different group result in one?

Tags: bosun

When using bosun query, the result goes like

**group**   **result**

{tag1}      result1

{tag2}      result2

...

How can I merge all the groups into one and the result turns out like

**group**   **result**

{mergedTag}      mergedResult1

Answer (score 0):

There's not  a lot of detail in the question, but you can use [`ungroup()`](https://bosun.org/expressions#ungroupnumberset-scalar) to first remove all tags, which lets you combine results from different groups into one.

If you then still need a single "merged" tag, you can add it in a further step using [`addtags()`](https://bosun.org/expressions#addtagsset-variantset-group-string-seriessetnumberset).